# How to fix Eclipse generating empty Javadoc comments?

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Recently Eclipse started to generate empty JavaDoc comments for methods:
/** */

No @param, @return etc.

Does anybody know the reason for this?

Comment: How are you generating them? By going above the function, typing `/**` and hitting enter?

Comment: By right clicking on method's name and then Source -> Generate Element Comment

Comment: Obvious question but any plugins you've installed recently? And even more obvious (sorry): is there anything on the Error Console?

Comment: @biziclop Have just took a look at installation history. The last plugin I installed was "Web Developer Tools" on the 18th March. But I don't know exactly when Eclipse started to generate empty comments. It may have started to do this ca. 2-3 weeks ago. There must be a problem  with one of my 2 workspaces. I use the same Eclipse instance while working with them. On the first workspace it generates full comments (with \@param, \@return etc.), but on the other empty comments.

Comment: @biziclop No errors in the Error view

Comment: Sounds like a workspace or config issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check the settings in 'Preferences > Java > Code Style > Code Templates > Comments > Methods'. The template pattern there should be

```
/**
 * ${tags}
 */
```

Comment: Should be accepted as best answer? Did the work for me too.